# Merge two datarames with different length on id and fill empty values with data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Edit**

I no longer need to do that (smh) but I'm keeping the post up for other's sorry for trouble.

So, I have two dataframes one has 1000 rows and second has 129. As you can see I have duplicates of ID's. I need to merge them together that data from second dataframe will duplicate accordingly to IDs of first one

**df1**

```
    id         genome
0    665639  ATGTTTG
1    665639  ATGTTTG
2    665639  ATGTTTG
3    665639  ATGTTTG
4    665639  ATGTTTG
995  702090  ATGTTTG
996  702092  ATGTTTG
997  702094  ATGTTTG
998  702098  ATGTTTG
999  702100  ATGTTTG
```

**df2**

```py
         id   genome                        lists             Present
0    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
1    679299  ATGTTTG  [[-, 447, A]]                              1
2    661921  ATGTTTG  [[-, 447, A], [C, 548, T], [C, 2626, T]]   1
3    673294  ATGTTTG  [[A, 850, G], [A, 2618, C]]                1
4    675730  ATGTTTG  [[-, 447, A],  [A, 2813, T]]               1
124  683468  ATGTTTG  [[G, 37, T],  [A, 1069, -]]                1
125  701722  ATGTTTG  [[G, 78, A], [-, 447, A], [A, 1023, -]]    1
126  702033  ATGTTTG  [[-, 447, A], [C, 3049, T]]                1
127  702050  ATGTTTG  [[-, 447, A], [A, 1034, T]]                1
128  702100  ATGTTTG                        NaN                  1
```

So after merging, I can get something like this

```py
         id   genome                        lists             Present
0    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
1    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
2    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
3    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
4    665639  ATGTTTG  [[C, 652, T], [A, 1860, -]]                1
.... ....... ....... ............. ......... ......... ..........
................ ..rest of the data.... ................ ........
```

Comment: Use ```pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='id')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case for `pd.merge_ordered`. It supports direct filling of missing values via `fill_method`. `ffill` should duplicate the entries, if the indices are already in the appropriate order. Otherwise it tries to write contiguous blocks (maybe over indices that don't match in order).

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html

i.e.

```py
pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2, on='id', fill_method='ffill', how="inner")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `pd.merge` ? This sould do the trick:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='id')
```